# Is there any other way to set tensor in object detection using ssdmobilenet

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am using a model of object detection and i am referring this link for fitting my image in model, thereby including the method "set_input_tensor" from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi/detect_picamera.py)

Now when i execute this line of code

```
def set_input_tensor(interpreter, image):

  tensor_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index']

  input_tensor = interpreter.tensor(tensor_index)()[0]
  
  input_tensor[:, :] = image
```

I am getting error of this line

```
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Shape of Image : (1, 320, 320, 3)

Shape of input_tensor : (320, 320, 3)

So I tried changing code like

```
input_tensor = image[0, :, :, :]
```

Since i am not implementing classes, i have not used `self` argument

please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can below is the code:-

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="model_path")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
input_data = image
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
labels =interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index']) 
scores =interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index']) 
num =interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index'])
```

Comment: interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)


ValueError: Failed to convert value into readable tensor.      
this is error i am facing

Comment: If you are using SSD300 tflite model which takes input shape of (1,300,300,3) and dtype is uint8 then you can use below code :-   
frame = cv2.imread("image_path")
    img_org = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = cv2.resize(img_org,(300,300))
    img = img.reshape(1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2]) # (1, 300, 300, 3)
    input_data = img.astype(np.uint8)

Comment: Can you please paste the output of input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
print(input_details)

Comment: [{'name': 'normalized_input_image_tensor', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 320, 320,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]

Comment: OKie then you can use below code to run you model on the image:-

`frame = cv2.imread("image_path")
img_org = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
img = cv2.resize(img_org,(320,320))
img = img.reshape(1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2]) # (1, 300, 300, 3) 
input_data = img`

Comment: ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got value of type UINT8 but expected type FLOAT32 for input 0, name: normalized_input_image_tensor 

when executing interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

Comment: also i mistakenly sent wrong input details .... this is real one .... [{'name': 'normalized_input_image_tensor', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 320, 320,   3], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([  1, 320, 320,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

Comment: You can try this one out :-

`frame = cv2.imread("image_path") img_org = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  img = cv2.resize(img_org,(320,320)) img = img.reshape(1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2]) # (1, 300, 300, 3)  input_data = img.astype(np.float32)`